# On click table td input append same tr every time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in JavaScript to repeat a same tr after,when i click the td elements.[image: Here the image]
My html code bellow:

```
<table id="tabl2" class="table time-table table-bordered table-striped budrow">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="cal-head">Rates</th>
        <th class="cal-head">Start date</th>
        <th class="cal-head">End date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="number" readonly placeholder="Rates">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" readonly id="start" placeholder="Start date">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="enddate" placeholder="End date">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried with this js but failed:

```
$('.budrow').click(function(){
   $(this).find('tr').append('<tr> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> </tr>');
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
var $table = $('#tabl2');
$table.click(function(e){
   var $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr');
   if (($tr.parent().prop("tagName") != 'THEAD') && $tr.is(":last-child"))
       $tr.after($tr.clone());
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bquhhpnd/6/).

Comment: Thanks Shaojiang Cai ,,Its works ..but want the tr will append only when i click last tr td element..not every tr..

Answer (score 1):

Bind the click event to the clicked element, select the current row using `closest()` and then append the new row using `after()` function:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var newRow = '<tr><td colspan="3">This is a new row</td></tr>';
  that.closest('tr').after(newRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button class="btn">click</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn">click</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn">click</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone and add the new row, also it will be better to use a add button separately

```
<button class="budrow">Add</button>
<table id="tabl2" class="table time-table table-bordered table-striped budrow">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="cal-head">Rates</th>
            <th class="cal-head">Start date</th>
            <th class="cal-head">End date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number" readonly placeholder="Rates" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" readonly id="start" placeholder="Start date" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="enddate" placeholder="End date" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $tr = $('#tabl2 tbody tr').eq(0);
    $('button.budrow').click(function () {
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $('#tabl2').append($clone);
        $clone.find('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
    });
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/032yodua/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.budrow tbody input').click(function(e){
        makeClone(e);
    });

    function makeClone(e){
        var newClone = $(e.target).closest("tr").clone();
        $("#tabl2 tbody").append(newClone);
        $(newClone).click(function(ev){
            makeClone(ev);
        })
    }
```